# Trying to create vbs file programmatically

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am writing a vb.net application that creates a vbs file. I've created the file and tested sending a line of text to it with no trouble. However, the second line has a problem.

```
File.WriteLine("set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")")
```

After the second quotation mark it stops reading it as a string or text. 
What am I missing?

Comment: `File.WriteLine("set WshShell = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")")`

Comment: Okay, any ideas why the vb with not run the vbs it just created? It keeps saying that Line 1 Char 1 is an Invalid Character. I have copied the script into a different notepad and it ran just fine.

Comment: Make public the line where the `File` handler is created. Looks like the file is opened as Unicode, which might result the file written starts with _byte order mark_. Inaccessible with `VBScript` script interpreter... Take a look with some hexa viewer or hexa editor.

Comment: Is a hex viewer or editor something that would have to be downloaded to different computers to be used or something that can be carried in the script?

Comment: The hex viewer is to allow _you_ to inspect the file to see if it has any Unicode byte order marks.  It would not be needed to run the script once it is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To represent a double quotation mark you escape it by putting two in a row

```
File.WriteLine("set WshShell = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")")
```

The funny thing is that even Stack Exchange markup also recognizes this

Comment: @The Blue Dog and Mike. Thank you. Seemed like that would of not come out right but it did. It is the little thing, right?

Comment: @Alenhj It's how nested double quotes are escaped in VBScript string literals.